# Why is my carousel-indicator in numbers?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

[image]

My code works fine, but I just don't get it why my indicators are in numbers...

```
<div id = "myCarousel" class = "carousel slide">

    <ol class = "carousel-idicators">

        <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class = "active"> </li>
        <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"> </li>
        <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"> </li>

    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
             <img class="img-responsive" width = "1600" height = "740" src="bohol.jpg" alt="bohol" align = "middle">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <img class="img-responsive" width = "1600" height = "740" src="cebu.jpg" alt="cebu">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <img class="img-responsive" width = "1600" height = "740"src="palawan.jpg" alt="palawan">
        </div>
    </div>                                  
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this. I've been trying to learn bootstrap 3, and i've just been following the same code on tutorials, but when I try to Run the code, it doesn't appear the same way as the tutorial had.

This would be my  section:

```
<head>
    <title>My First Web Page</title>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">   
</head>
```

Comment: can you post your `<head>` section, in particular the part where you link external stylesheets and javascript?

Comment: @mastazi i've posted it above

Comment: You are missing jquery and bootstrap javascripts there, unless you load them in your footer. Be aware that Jquery has to be loaded first, than your bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the link to your js files. 
First you have to link Jquery library and then the bootstrap js, like the example below (please note that the actual path depends on where your js files are):

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, every Bootstrap component which is in the following page needs javascript: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: (as you can see the Carousel is there too)